# According to PEP8, should I always break my lines before the 79 characters limit?

Tags: python, pep8

I've read the [section about line length in PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length) and have understood when to break my code lines. But I'm not sure whether I should break lines *uniformly* when giving parameters. Explaining:

Should I break the line only when it reaches the length limit, like this (`servidor_os`):

```
servidor_khan = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
servidor_os = models.ForeignKey(
    EquipamientoOs,
    null=True,
    blank=True,
    related_name='servidores',
    verbose_name='SO del servidor')
cantidad_equipo = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Or do it always in order to keep it uniform, like this:

```
servidor_khan = models.BooleanField(
    blank=True,
    default=False)
servidor_os = models.ForeignKey(
    EquipamientoOs,
    null=True,
    blank=True,
    related_name='servidores',
    verbose_name='SO del servidor')
cantidad_equipo = models.IntegerField(
    default=0)
```

Comment: most of the updated versions of ide's like PyCharm these days allows 120 chars in one line. There is no hard and fast rule that you should have 80 chars. The idea is to make your code look clean

Comment: I guess that if you always do it, it makes the code look more uniform, but it also means that there's less code per screen, and I try to avoid spreading class or function definitions over too many screens. Personally, I only break lines when they need to be broken, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: If you want the code to fit onto a punch card or on a VT100 console, 80 characters is the limit. If you are developing on a phone, e.g. Pythonista, the limit can actually be useful.

Comment: I'm using Sublime with a code linter and I set the length limit to 109, but what if I (someday) have something like 150 chars?

Answer (score 0):

Generally folks only break a procedure call across multiple lines if it would exceed the line length.  Since most calls fit on one line, this tends to keep more code on the screen at one time.

You generally want to keep as many lines of code on the screen as possible (without sacrificing clarity) so you can glance between them quickly when reading and trying to understand the code.

This is one of Python's advantages as a language.  By eliminating close brackets at the end of blocks, you tend to have more code on the screen at once, on average.